# Just installed baldur's gate original saga in ubuntu 16.04 64-bit and there is no sound

Tags: 16.04, sound, 64-bit

I'm new to games, and apologies if this is posted in the wrong place. I have just installed baldur's gate original saga from a .sh file. The installation went great. Everything seems to be working fine. The only problem is that there is no sound. I took the suggestion from the support website (GOG) to install libasound2 libraries. But there is still no sound. Does anyone have any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [support website](https://www.gog.com/support/baldurs_gate_the_original_saga/i_dont_have_sound_in_a_32_bit_game) also says to install the 'dependencies listed in the game's requirements', Baldur's Gate Original Saga isn't on GOG anymore, but the [Enhanced Edition](https://www.gog.com/game/baldurs_gate_enhanced_edition) lists the packages to be installed (in the pane on the right). Based on that, you'll want to run this command:

```
sudo apt install libc6:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-data:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion. I tried installing those dependencies, but there is still no sound.  I was hoping to play the original, but maybe I should try and see if the sound works on the enhanced edition.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but so is the game. I just faced same problem today. What worked for me:

Edit the file `~/GOG Games/Baldurs Gate The Original Saga/wine_standalone/wine.shlib`

In `wine_export()` section change line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CURRENT_DIR/lib/:$CURRENT_DIR/lib/i386-linux-gnu"
```

to

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="usr/lib:usr/lib"
```